# ZF2 setJsonpCallback() returns wrong content-type (application/json instead of application/javascript)

Tags: zend-framework2, jsonp

we are developing with Zend Framework 2.4 and have an API that should support jsonp callbacks.

Unfortunatelly, Chrome doesn't like the content-type it returns. It is application/json but needs to be application/javascript.

```
return $jsonModel->setJsonpCallback($jsonpCallback);
```

Is anybody aware of a ZF2 bug in that case?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately JsonStrategy doesn't look at JsonModel for a jsonp callback. If I had to guess, it's due to JsonModel not exposing the value of JsonModel::$jsonCallback. JsonStrategy will look at the renderer, JsonRenderer by default, for a jsonp callback and apply a content-type of application/javascript or application/json accordingly.

In your situation, JsonRenderer wasn't set with a jsonp callback so JsonStrategy is returning a content-type of application/json. You can correct this by accessing the JsonRenderer from the controller and setting the jsonp callback value.

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $jsonModel = new JsonModel();
        $jsonModel->setVariables(array(
            'ping' => 'pong',
        ));

        /** @var \Zend\View\Renderer\JsonRenderer $jsonRenderer */
        $jsonRenderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewJsonRenderer');
        $jsonRenderer->setJsonpCallback('wakawaka');

        return $jsonModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was already editing the ZF2 core to solve it but your solution just does the job.